# ADT installation on ubuntu - adb & fastboot is not working?

Tags: android, ubuntu, adb, fastboot

I am trying to install ADT without using standalone installer.With help of this guide http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2302780

I am using ubuntu 13.04 , so when I try to call adb or fastboot, it alwasys ends up as permission denied.

```
    parthiban@upk-sys:~$ adb
    bash: /media/parthiban/New Volume1/idea-IC-129.1359/android-sdk-linux/platform- tools/adb: Permission denied    
    parthiban@upk-sys:~$ fastboot
    bash: /media/parthiban/New Volume1/idea-IC-129.1359/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/fastboot: Permission denied
```

I have edited .bashrc as instructed in that  guide . Any idea ??

Answer (score 2):

Seems like your device needs to be accessed by a privileged user. Simply put 'sudo' in front of the command adb or fastboot. 
Or you could try and restart the adb server with the root account.
Like 
    sudo -s
    adb kill-server
    adb start-server
Afterwards you should be able to call adb (or fastboot)